# On minimizing a summation

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have the following inequality:

$$ A > \Big(\frac{1}{2k}-\frac{1}{2n}\Big)n^{2} \tag{*}$$

where $n\geq k$ and $n$ and $k$ are both positive integers. We also know that

$$ A = \sum_{j=1}^{k}|S_j| \left( |S_j| - 1 \right) $$

where $|S_j|\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ for each $j\in[k]$ and $\sum_{j=1}^{k}|S_j|=n$. Now, I am trying to find values of $|S_j|$ such that the equation $(*)$ holds. Moreover, I would want to find a lower bound for $\min_{j \in [r]}\{|S_j|\}$ such that $(*)$ holds.

---

My attempt:

Let $T$ denote $\min_{j\in[k]}\{S_j\}$ and $R:=\Big(\frac{1}{2k}-\frac{1}{2n}\Big)n^2$. By this, equation $(*)$ becomes the following:

$k\cdot T(T-1)>R \Leftrightarrow T^{2}-T>\frac{R}{k}$

When solving this equation, Wolframalpha seems to get me the following:

$T>\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{4R+1}+1)=\frac{1}{2}\Bigg[1+\sqrt{4n^{2}\frac{\Big(\frac{1}{2r}-\frac{1}{2n}\Big)}{r}+1}\Bigg]$.

However, if possible, I would like to be able to express the lower bound for $T$ as a function of $n$ in a way that $(*)$ would hold.

Comment: I don't get the question. Let's insert some values: let $k=2$, $|S_1| = 1$, $|S_2| = 3$. Then $n = 4$, $A = 6$, $R = 2$, which means $A > R$ in other words equation (*) holds. $\min_{j \in [k]}\{|S_j|\} = |S_1| = 1$, and this value cannot be lower, because $|S_j|\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$, hence it is the lower bound. Did the question miss some detail?